# Where can I ask about a Michael Jackson tribute show copyright issue?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which site should I ask this question?:

> I'm trying to put on a Michael Jackson tribute show where I have a
> live band play the music along with the studio vocals (here is a great
> example of what I'm trying to do just on a bigger scale
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMqvRj_gv84).
>
> The issue is I don't know how to get the vocals legally and if I could
> legally put on the show without acquiring the rights to the entire
> version of each of the 12 songs. If anyone out there knows what I can
> do in this situation or any resources to help me out please let me
> know.

Where should I ask about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

We have a [Law site](https://law.stackexchange.com) that appears to have a [very similar question to this already](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/rights-for-live-performances), maybe the answer there tells you enough that you don't need to ask your own question. If not...

Law has a [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) tag

> For questions about the property right inherent in a creative work. Please see the [tag wiki](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/copyright/info) and [FAQ](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/i-have-a-question-about-copyright-what-should-i-read-before-i-ask-it) before asking the question.

So don't forget to check those links if you want to ask your own question.